# "RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap" trying to pass Bitmap from Activity to a Service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-bitmap

I'm writing a small Android program in Android Studio that uses MediaProjection to grab a screenshot of the whole screen and then I want to pass that screenshot as a Bitmap to my System Overlay (based on the chatheads example). When the MediaProjection runs and the Imagereader creates the bitmaps, I'm passing the bitmap into a class global variable so I can pass it into my System Overlay service and display it. I'm running into an issue where when the Imageview inside the service tries to read the bmp, I get an error as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@347a4d5
```

From my understanding, the garbage collector quickly eats up the passed Bitmap and when the System Overlay tries to grab it, the data is gone. Could someone point me in the right direction on how to keep the bitmap?

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.chatheads;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.OrientationEventListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button startService,stopService;


    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static String STORE_DIRECTORY;
    private static int IMAGES_PRODUCED;
    private static final String SCREENCAP_NAME = "screencap";
    private static final int VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAGS = DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;
    private static MediaProjection sMediaProjection;

    private MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;
    private ImageReader mImageReader;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Display mDisplay;
    private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    private int mDensity;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    private int mRotation;
    private OrientationChangeCallback mOrientationChangeCallback;

    private Image image = null;
    private Bitmap bitmap = null;

    Globals sharedData = Globals.getInstance();

    public Bitmap getObjectContainer() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    private class ImageAvailableListener implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

            FileOutputStream fos = null;


            try {
                image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage();
                if (image != null) {
                    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                    int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                    int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                    int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * mWidth;

                    // create bitmap
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
                    sharedData.setScreenshot(bitmap);

                    // write bitmap to a file
                   // fos = new FileOutputStream(STORE_DIRECTORY + "/myscreen_" + IMAGES_PRODUCED + ".png");
                    //bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                    IMAGES_PRODUCED++;
                    //Log.e(TAG, "captured image: " + IMAGES_PRODUCED);
                    String s = ("captured image: " + String.valueOf(IMAGES_PRODUCED));
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast1.show();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (fos!=null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (bitmap!=null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }

                if (image!=null) {
                    image.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class OrientationChangeCallback extends OrientationEventListener {
        public OrientationChangeCallback(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            synchronized (this) {
                final int rotation = mDisplay.getRotation();
                if (rotation != mRotation) {
                    mRotation = rotation;
                    try {
                        // clean up
                        if(mVirtualDisplay != null) mVirtualDisplay.release();
                        if(mImageReader != null) mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);

                        // re-create virtual display depending on device width / height
                        createVirtualDisplay();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class MediaProjectionStopCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            Log.e("ScreenCapture", "stopping projection.");
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(mVirtualDisplay != null) mVirtualDisplay.release();
                    if(mImageReader != null) mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);
                    if(mOrientationChangeCallback != null) mOrientationChangeCallback.disable();
                    sMediaProjection.unregisterCallback(MediaProjectionStopCallback.this);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sharedData.setValue(1);

        // call for the projection manager
        mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

        // start projection
        Button startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startProjection();
            }
        });

        // stop projection
        Button stopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopProjection();
            }
        });

        // start capture handling thread
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                mHandler = new Handler();
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }.start();


        startService=(Button)findViewById(R.id.startService);
        stopService=(Button)findViewById(R.id.stopService);

        startService.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startService(new Intent(getApplication(), ChatHeadService.class));

            }
        });
        stopService.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopService(new Intent(getApplication(), ChatHeadService.class));

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            sMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);

            if (sMediaProjection != null) {
                File externalFilesDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
                if (externalFilesDir != null) {
                    STORE_DIRECTORY = externalFilesDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/screenshots/";
                    File storeDirectory = new File(STORE_DIRECTORY);
                    if (!storeDirectory.exists()) {
                        boolean success = storeDirectory.mkdirs();
                        if (!success) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "failed to create file storage directory.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "failed to create file storage directory, getExternalFilesDir is null.");
                    return;
                }

                // display metrics
                DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                mDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
                mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

                // create virtual display depending on device width / height
                createVirtualDisplay();

                // register orientation change callback
                mOrientationChangeCallback = new OrientationChangeCallback(this);
                if (mOrientationChangeCallback.canDetectOrientation()) {
                    mOrientationChangeCallback.enable();
                }

                // register media projection stop callback
                sMediaProjection.registerCallback(new MediaProjectionStopCallback(), mHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    /****************************************** UI Widget Callbacks *******************************/
    private void startProjection() {
        startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void stopProjection() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (sMediaProjection != null) {
                    sMediaProjection.stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /****************************************** Factoring Virtual Display creation ****************/
    private void createVirtualDisplay() {
        // get width and height
        Point size = new Point();
        mDisplay.getSize(size);
        mWidth = size.x;
        mHeight = size.y;

        // start capture reader
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
        mVirtualDisplay = sMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(SCREENCAP_NAME, mWidth, mHeight, mDensity, VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAGS, mImageReader.getSurface(), null, mHandler);
        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageAvailableListener(), mHandler);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
package com.example.chatheads;    
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ChatHeadService extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private ImageView chatHead;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params;

    Globals sharedData = Globals.getInstance();



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int h = displayMetrics.heightPixels, w = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888; // see other conf types
        final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, conf); // this creates a MUTABLE bitmap
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setAlpha(60);
        Rect rect=new Rect(0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        canvas.drawRect(rect,paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, h, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, w, 0, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(w, 0, h, w, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, w, paint);


        chatHead = new ImageView(this);
        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.face1);

        params= new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 1000;







        //this code is for dragging the chat head
        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;
            boolean isExpanded = false;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();

                    int n = sharedData.getValue();
                    //Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf(n), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    //toast1.show();
                    if (isExpanded == true){
                        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.face1);
                        isExpanded=false;
                        params.x = 0;
                        params.y = 1000;
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                    }
                    else{
                        //chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.clear);
                        Bitmap bmp2 = sharedData.getScreenshot();

                        chatHead.setImageBitmap(bmp2);
                        isExpanded = true;
                        params.x = 0;
                        params.y = 0;
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                    }
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.test);
                    return true;
                /*case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX
                            + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY
                            + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                    return true;*/
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatHead != null)
            windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Globals**

```
package com.example.chatheads;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Globals {

    private static Globals instance = new Globals();
    // Getter-Setters
    public static Globals getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static void setInstance(Globals instance) {
        Globals.instance = instance;
    }

    private Globals() {

    }

    private int testi;
    private Bitmap bmpscreenshot;

    public Bitmap getScreenshot(){
        return bmpscreenshot;
    }

    public void setScreenshot(Bitmap bmp){
        this.bmpscreenshot = bmp;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return testi;
    }

    public void setValue(int testi) {
        this.testi = testi;
    }

}
```

Comment: Cleanest and safe solution would be to store your image into temporary file in your apps data or cache directory then read it.

Comment: I would agree to @Pawel. There is also a limit on how much bytes you can pass to the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be calling **bitmap.recycle()** too soon. Call it after the service has actually processed the data.

Comment: I did a quick test and commented out the recycle line and it worked great. I'll create a global boolean that will let the activity know when it's okay to recycle. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pass a Bitmap from Activity to service means, convert the bitmap into ByteArray

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
Bitmap b; // your bitmap
ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
i.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
startService(i);
```

> Override onStartCommand in your service

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"),0,getIntent()
                .getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);    
    return null;
}
```